# Using for loops to generate html content

Tags: r, htmltools

I am trying to generate html content using a for loop, but I am having problems in how the content looks in the html.

Lets say I have a Rhtml template and I want to generate paragraphs in a for loop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--begin.rcode, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE
library(htmltools)
paragraphs = c("Paragraph1","Paragraph2","Paragraph3")
tags$div(
  for(i in paragraphs){
    print(tags$p(i))
    }
  )
end.rcode-->
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the html output is like this:

```
## <p>Paragraph1</p>
## <p>Paragraph2</p>
## <p>Paragraph3</p>
```

And what I need is just three normal html paragraphs.
How can I do this using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the loop outside of `tags$div`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--begin.rcode, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE
library(htmltools)
paragraphs = c("Paragraph1","Paragraph2","Paragraph3")
p <- list()
for(i in paragraphs){
  p <- c(p, list(tags$p(i)))
}
tags$div(p)
end.rcode-->
</body>
</html>
```

[image: html]

This can also be written with `purr::map`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--begin.rcode, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE
library(htmltools)
paragraphs = c("Paragraph1","Paragraph2","Paragraph3")
tags$div(purrr::map(paragraphs, tags$p))
end.rcode-->
</body>
</html>
```